# Visual C# 2008. CRUD Example using Dataset, DataRow with an Access Mdb

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, ms-access-2007, crud

I'm using Visual Studio C# 2008
I've created (visually) a dataset that points to a mdb file (Access 2007)
This DataSet is called "EstacionarDataSet"

```
EstacionarDataSet ed = new EstacionarDataSet();
DataRow newRow = ed.Tables[0].NewRow();
newRow["patente"] = tb_Patente.Text;
newRow["numerobox"] = tb_Box.Text;
newRow["fechahora_ingreso"] = DateTime.Now;
ed.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
```

- This code is executed in a Form2 (not mainform), where I'm trying to insert a new record into the only table mdb file has (this code doesn't work, but doesn't give any exception).
- The mainform contains a **System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView** component, attached to this mdb file, which works fine, it shows the records correctly, etc. (PS: I added some sample records using Access)
- **I'm needing some code samples for adding a new row, updating, and deleting... Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how DataAdapter works:

read this article

[DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx)

or many other in the web.

Then All you need is a connection object to the MDB, A configured dataadapter with select insert and update commands (can be easily done with the wizard).

and fill a table or dataset with the data, binding it to the gridview.

Comment: The wizzard has already created lot of code, and I guess it has the connection string, etc. because when Mainform shows, the DataGridView loads the data from the mdb table. 

Will I need also need to create that connection object, dataadapter, etc.?

Where is that wizzard you point, located?

Thanks

Comment: The data adapters it probably already exists if you got the data. I will checkout your project and see later today.

Comment: ok, got your sln. do you need to append and delete rows to the grid ?